# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tokenfield is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I'm new of jQuery and Bootstrap. everything was working perfectly until i decided to use the Bootstrap Tokenfield to add a search system based.

[Bootstrap tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/)

Now when i try to execute my ,jsp page i get: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tokenfield is not a function

This is my .jsp page

**JQuery import**

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<title></title>

</head>
```

**Component declaration**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />
$('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
})
```

Where am I doing worng? I'm forgetting to bring something?

Comment: there is no  token field `id`that you select and no function in bootstrap that has token field

Comment: I guess missed to include JS "bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js". Check for js bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js and included this too.

Comment: the tokenfiled is a function which is not in the default package that you are loqding you should import his private package which is not the case

Comment: What Premanand K said. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the DOM are telling you that it didn't know that tokenfield function because it is not declared in your header so you have to load those 2 files first before using it :

1 - load the `dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js`

2 - load the `dist/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css` in your HTML

and let your code as it is

NB : those 2 libraris need as requirements: jQuery 1.9+, Bootstrap 3+ (only CSS)

the libraries link is here : http://www.github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you have to include `bootstrap-tokenfield.js` in index.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />

$('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
})
```